# AngularJS Comparison showing false in all cases

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing a mobile app using the Ionic Framework. I have an array of objects as described here (app.js):

```
$scope.versesList = [
    {id:"1" , value:'5', checked:($scope.selectedItem==this)} , 
    {id:"2" , value:'10', checked:($scope.selectedItem==this)} , 
    {id:"3" , value:'15', checked:($scope.selectedItem==this)} , 
    {id:"4" , value:'20', checked:($scope.selectedItem==this)}
];
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.versesList[1];
```

Here's the code that produces my output :

```
<div class="item">
      <pre ng-bind="versesList | json"></pre>
</div>
```

Here's the output :

```
[
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "value" : "5",
        "checked" : false
    },
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "value" : "10",
        "checked" : false
    },
    {
        "id" : "3",
        "value" : "15",
        "checked" : false
    },
    {
        "id" : "4",
        "value" : "20",
        "checked" : false
    }
]
```

I would like to have the second JSONObject's checked to display true. I doubt whether the comparison for the checked item is causing this error.

Any code help would be appreciated

Comment: Object comparison with `==` only works when the object is the same reference. Why not just compare ID's?

Comment: When you construct `$scope.versesList` the `selectedItem` will always be undefined, is it? You are declaring the selectedItem afterwards. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Developer declaring selectedItem before versesList gives no output at all

Comment: @tymeJV doing so gives me a true value for all the cases